# Editing posed mesh for blend shapes

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, pose-mode

I have rigged, weight painted, and posed this model so that the arm is raised.  I have the Display Modifier in Edit Mode and the Adjust edit cage to modifier result turned on.

My question is, when I go into edit mode of the mesh for my blend shapes, I select a vertex to move via pressing G, I move left, and the vertex moves in a different direction (as illustrated in the screenshot below)

[image: vert moving example]
It gets worse for the legs, especially legs in a folded position.  The vert flies sometimes in the opposite direction.  I tried to translate along the axis by pressing z x or y, but their local axis are all different due to the mesh posed in different positions.

I just want to move the vert along the standard global axis.

Is there any way to do that?  It has been a very tough time editing posed meshes.

Comment: I've tried to recreate the conditions of your problem, but I failed: my vertices go exactly where I want them to go. I think you should upload your .blend file, to get examinated.